# UDP socket receive not working in background Service

Tags: java, android, sockets, service, udp

I need to create a UDP socket into a background Service in order to receive packets at any time. My class inherits Service and overrides onStartCommand():

```
public class NetworkListener extends Service
{
private DatagramSocket socket = null;
private int state = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    System.out.println("Here");
    if (intent != null)
    {
        System.out.println("Before while");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[50];   // Socket's buffer

        try {   socket = new DatagramSocket(4415);  }
        catch (SocketException e) {   e.printStackTrace();    }

        DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);    // Receiving packet

        while (this.state == 0)
        {
            try {   socket.receive(data);   }
            catch (IOException e)   {   e.printStackTrace();    }
            System.out.println("In while");
            try {   parse(data);    }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)  {   e.printStackTrace();    }
        }
        socket.close();
    }
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

When I execute the code, I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.electricfeel.NetworkListener@41e8a588 with Intent { cmp=com.example.electricfeel/.NetworkListener }: java.lang.NullPointerException

 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.electricfeel.NetworkListener.onStartCommand(NetworkListener.java:53)
```

The relevant line is this one:

```
 try {   socket.receive(data);   }
```

And this is how I start the service in my HomeActivity:

```
this.m_networkListenerService = new Intent(this, NetworkListener.class);
this.startService(this.m_networkListenerService);
```

What is wrong in my code? Thank you!

**EDIT:** Ok it is fixed. I forgot to add this line to my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

But now I have another error:

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
```

From what I have understood it's because I'm on a main thread and thus not allowed to perform such operation...

Comment: Socket is null.  This means the constructor of DatagramSocket threw an exception.  I'd check what it threw and look for problems there.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`. But now I have another error:

`Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)`

Comment: Thats just what it says.  You need to move the networking code into an AsyncTask or Thread.

Comment: Yes that's what I figured out. Damn it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am suffering from this same issue with no luck at all finding a solution. my .receive() method isn't doing anything at all. It gets to that point in code and just stops. No exceptions or anything.